# AngularJS bind returning json data to template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am unable to find easy steps on how to  bind a returning json object to a angular template [The template is also remote]

e.g. data in success callback is JSON and I want to bind it to a template before display

```
app.controller('jobs', ['$scope', 'wpHttp', function ($scope, wpHttp) {
    $scope.buildMatches = function (job_id) {
        $scope.matchesHtml = 'Loading matches please wait ...';
        wpHttp("get_employer_job_matches").success(function (data) {
                        // bind json to template similar to mustache.js?
                        $scope.matchesHtml = data;
                    });
                }; etc.......
```

I am using bootstrap.ui and I am want to load the rendered template as follows

```
<tab select="buildMatches(job.ID)" heading="Matches">
  <div data-ng-bind-html="matchesHtml"></div>
</tab>
```

@ azium 
Yes the JSON data is returned as expected everything is working fine, I think the issue can be solved using a custom directive, I want to bind data to templateUrl: views_url + "matches.php" only when tab select="buildMatches(job.ID)" heading="Matches" is selected.

```
(function (angular, wp_localize) {

    var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    var theme_url = wp_localize.theme_url;
    var views_url = theme_url + "/angular-apps/employer-profile/views/";
    var language = lang;

    app.service('wpHttp', ['$http', function ($http) {
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            };
            return function (action, data) {
                var queryStr = "action=" + action;
                if (data) {
                    queryStr += "&data=" + JSON.stringy(data);
                }
                request.data = queryStr;
                return $http(request);
            };
        }]);


    app.controller('jobs', ['$scope', 'wpHttp', function ($scope, wpHttp) {

            $scope.lang = language;
            $scope.img = theme_url + "/images/front_page/candidate-mummy.png";
            $scope.questionnaireHtml = $scope.matchesHtml = '';
            $scope.buildMatches = function (job_id) {
                $scope.matchesHtml = 'Loading matches please wait ...';
                wpHttp("get_employer_job_matches").success(function (data) {
                    $scope.matchesHtml = data;
                });
            };
            $scope.buildQuestionnaire = function () {
                $scope.matchesHtml = 'Loading please wait';
            };

            wpHttp("get_employer_jobs").success(function (data) {
                $scope.jobs = data;
            });
        }]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                        templateUrl: views_url + "create-jobs.php",
                        controller: 'jobs'
                    }).when('/jobs', {
                templateUrl: views_url + "list-jobs.php",
                controller: 'jobs'
            });
        }
    ]);

    app.directive('ngMatchesHtml', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: views_url + "matches.php"
        }
    });



})(angular, wp_localize_employer_profile);
```

Comment: There are few things that might be the problem. 1) Do you have `ngSanitize` or something like that in your app? You need to include that module in order to use `bind-html` properly. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize 2) Does your data response look like you expect? 3) Can you post your code for the `wpHttp` service?

Comment: You say it is json but you are trying to use the full response as html...doesn't make sense. What does response structure look like?

Comment: Just noticed this line:

`queryStr += "&data=" + JSON.stringy(data);`

I think you meant to use `JSON.stringify(data);`